# Shared divisor of perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Working on a problem to do with equivalence relations I stumbled on the following question: If (working in $\mathbb{N}$) $y \ \big |\ k^2$ and $y\ \big|\ q^2$ is there any way of proving that $y$ divides $kq$? My intuition says that such a statement is true but I can't think of a way to prove it (or find a counterexample.)

Comment: The case $y = 1$ is trivial. For $y > 1$, consider a prime $p$ dividing $y$, write $y = p^r\cdot m$ with $p \nmid m$. What does $y \mid k^2$ say about the power of $p$ in the prime factorisation of $k$?

Comment: @DanielFischer That the power of $p$ in $k$ is greater than or equal to $r/2$? What if $m$ divides a $q$ in the power factorisation of $k$? Sorry but I'm not seeing as far as you at the moment.

Comment: Yes, the power of $p$ in $k$ must be at least $r/2$. The same holds for $q$, so the power of $p$ in $kq$ is at least $r$. Since that holds for every prime dividing $y$ …

Comment: Lightbulb! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, for notational purposes I will use $a|b^{2}$ and $a|c^{2}$ and prove $a|bc$.

Let $a = p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\dots p_{l}^{\alpha_{l}}$, $b = q_{1}^{\beta_{1}}\dots q_{m}^{\beta_{m}}$ and $c = r_{1}^{\gamma_{1}}\dots r_{n}^{\gamma^{n}}$ be prime decompositions.

Then $a|b^{2} \Rightarrow l \leq m$ and also that we may reorder $q_{1}, \dots, q_{m}$ such that $p_{i} = q_{i}$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, l\}$. Similarly $a|c^{2} \Rightarrow l \leq n$ and we may reorder $r_{1}, \dots, r_{n}$ such that $p_{i} = r_{i}$. Hence $q_{i} = r_{i}$.

Further $a|b^{2} \Rightarrow \alpha_{i} \leq 2\beta_{i}$ and similarly $\alpha_{i} \leq 2\gamma_{i}$. Together these inequalities gives $2\alpha_{i} \leq 2\beta_{i} + 2\gamma_{i} \Rightarrow \alpha_{i} \leq \beta_{i} + \gamma_{i}$.

Hence $a = p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\dots p_{l}^{\alpha_{l}}|p_{1}^{\beta_{1} + \gamma_{1}}\dots p_{l}^{\beta_{l} + \gamma_{l}} = q_{1}^{\beta_{1}}r_{1}^{\gamma_{1}}\dots q_{l}^{\beta_{l}}r_{l}^{\gamma_{l}}$.

Then $q_{1}^{\beta_{1}}r_{1}^{\gamma_{1}}\dots q_{l}^{\beta_{l}}r_{l}^{\gamma_{l}}|bc$.

Finally by the transitivity of division we have $a|bc$.